# Is there an option to whitelist email for staged rollout in Playstore developer console?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

How can I whitelist an email id in staged rollout option?

Use case : Have the new version available for QA and other stakeholders after publishing - And before rolling out to the second group.

I checked these.
1. All options inside APK to see email whitelisting
2. Checked if the new apk available for Publish console admin's playstore - Not there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to first release your app to a group of user first, who will test it and then if it's fine you want to release it to everyone, right? For this you can upload your APK in *beta* and then set up a list of testers by adding their email addresses in the list of beta testers.

Comment: @camelCaseCoder Thanks for the answer. The answer to my question is NO. In a staged roll out we cannot control the user group. The only way is to do a beta release as you have mentioned.